# Return erb from inside enumerable block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, erb, enumerable, enumerator

What's the best way to return erb from an enumerable?

Currently, this is my code:

```
<% @projects.collect do |p| %>
  <%= react_component("Project", p) %>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to use something like this:

```
<%= @projects.collect{ |p| react_component("Project", p) } %>
```

Is there a generally accepted best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it's a little wonky to mix erb and react directly like this.  So, if it were me, I would just create a higher order React component that takes in your projects collection and spits out children components itself.  Something like;

```
 <%= react_component ("Projects", {projects: @projects}) %>

 <script>
     var Projects = React.createClass({
         render: function(){
             <div>
                 { this.props.projects.map(function (project){
                     return <Project p={project}/>
                 }); }
             </div>
         }
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it felt a bit wonky to be honest. I like this solution a lot more